What factors need to be taken into account in assessing the meaning of "the will of God" in Mark 3:35?
Mark 3:35  ESV

"For whoever does the will of God, he is my brother and sister and mother." [My emphasis]

Here the will of God is thelema.
Romans 9:18 ESV

"So then he has mercy on whomever he wills, and he hardens whomever he wills." [thelei/he wills].

Here in Ro 9:18 thelei, a verb, expresses God's will in varied terms. God's will may vary from mercy to hardening, but is still God's will just seen in different ways.
What factors  determine the meaning of "the will of God" in Mark 3:35?


For I came down from heaven, not to do mine own will, but the will of him that sent me. And this is the Father's will which hath sent me, that of all which he hath given me I should lose nothing, but should raise it up again at the last day. And this is the will of him that sent me, that every one which seeth the Son, and believeth on him, may have everlasting life: and I will raise him up at the last day. [John 6:38-40 KJV]


For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. And I know that his commandment is life everlasting: whatsoever I speak therefore, even as the Father said unto me, so I speak. [John 12:9,50 KJV]

Judgment is God's 'strange work'. He does not delight in the death of the wicked :

Say unto them, As I live, saith the Lord GOD, I have no pleasure in the death of the wicked; but that the wicked turn from his way and live: turn ye, turn ye from your evil ways; for why will ye die, O house of Israel? [Ezekiel 33:11 KJV]

The will of the Father is that none whom he has given to the Son should be lost ; that every one who sees the Son (with the eye of faith) may have 'everlasting life' ; his commandment is 'life everlasting' in an 'everlasting testament' and in a 'new creation'.
And how should these things be accomplished in sinful men, with an origin in sin and death ? By faith, and by faith alone . . . . . . through the One whom God has sent into the world.

Jesus answered and said unto them, This is the work of God, that ye believe on him whom he hath sent. [John 6:29 KJV]


His singularly overarching work. +1

The OP's question essentially asks about two cognate forms of the word θέλω (theló) = "desires, wills, wants"; namely the verb θέλω (theló) and the noun θέλημα (thelema).  The NT is very clear about exactly what God's will is:

1 Tim 2:3, 4 - This is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Savior, who desires [θέλω (theló)] all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.
Matt 18:14 - In the same way, your Father in heaven is not willing that any of these little ones should perish.
2 Peter 3:9 - The Lord does not delay the promise, as some esteem slowness, but is patient toward you, not willing for any to perish, but all to come to repentance.
1 Tim 4:10, For to this end we toil and strive, because we have our hope set on the living God, who is the Saviour of all people, especially of those who believe.
Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honor because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”

Now, it clear that if God wants all people to be saved, He also want all people to "do His will" -

Matt 7:21 - Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only he who does the will of My Father in heaven.
Matt 12:50 - For whoever shall do the will of My Father who is in the heavens, he is My brother and sister and mother."
Mark 3:35 - For whoever shall do the will of God, he is My brother and sister and mother."
1 John 2:17 - The world is passing away, along with its desires; but whoever does the will of God remains forever.

Now we are also told that:

Acts 17:30 - Although God overlooked the ignorance of earlier times, He now commands all people everywhere to repent.

Therefore, to do the "will of God" is to repent and do the works of God:

John 6:28, 29 - Then they inquired, “What must we do to perform the works of God?” Jesus replied, “The work of God is this: to believe in the One He has sent.”

Romans 9
With the above background, what does Rom 9 teach about saving and hardening people's hearts?
For example, some will specifically quote v13: “Jacob I loved and Esau I hated”; and v14, “I will have mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have compassion”.  V19-23 appears to be the “magna carter” of limited atonement.  So, is Rom 9 really discussing limited atonement, despite all the many Bible references listed earlier?  How should we understand this passage?
We should observe the following facts:

The chosen nation status of Israel was about their vocation as evangelists to teach the world, not their status as saved.  See “Israel”.  This is confirmed by the analogy of the potter in v21.
Romans 9 is NOT discussing individuals.  God chose the nation that came from Jacob to do the job of providing the spiritual enlightenment to the world and being the progenitors of Christ.  See v 3-5.
If Paul is teaching limited atonement in Rom 9 then he is very confused because v6 and v7 teaches the opposite.  “… not all who are descended from Israel are Israel.  Nor because they are his descendants are they all Abraham’s children.”  That is, being “chosen” (or “elect”) descendant of Abraham does not make a person a member of spiritual Israel; rather it was whether that person becomes a person of the promise, that choses to accept God’s grace.
Paul’s summary and conclusion to his long (and admittedly difficult) argument in Rom 9:30-32 is equally clear – being a physical member of literal Israel does not make a person a real spiritual Israelite.  The real question is whether a person becomes a person “of the promise”, that is, decides to accept Jesus.  (See also v24 where Paul again confirms that the chosen are called from both Jews and Gentiles.)
Loved vs hated (v13):  This is a piece of classic Hebrew idiom that employs rhetorical hyperbole.  It is obvious that God loves all people and hates no one because “God is love” (1 John 4:8, 16).  See “Love”.  A simple comparison with Mal 1:2, 3 (that v13 quotes), Luke 14:26, 27 and Gen 29:31-33 (where the word “hated” is used) shows this Hebrew idiom well.
Background:  Passages like Jer 7:4 clearly show that the Jews regarded their position as the chosen people of God as the source of their spiritual pride.  That is, because of all that God had bestowed on them, they believed they must be saved and were guaranteed God’s favor and eternal life.  Thus, the doctrine of free grace came as a very big shock.  Paul is at pains to point out that not all who are (physical or genetic) Israelites are (spiritual) Israelites.  Gentiles could become spiritual Israelites by “the promise”.  God was now selecting gentiles to be His representatives without excluding the Jews.  Even in ancient literal Israel, membership of Israel was entirely voluntary not genetic.

Will of God
Central to this whole question is the sovereignty of otherwise of the will of God.  Calvin believed that God’s will was absolute, but the Bible is far more nuanced.  I have previously listed many verses saying that God wants all people to be saved, but we know that not all will be saved.  Here are some further examples.

Matt 6:10 – “God’s will be done on earth”; we know this often not the case.  See also Luke 11:2.
Matt 18:14 – “In the same way your Father in heaven is not willing that any of these little ones should perish.”  However, we know that some will perish because all grow up to be sinners.
Mark 3:35 – “For whoever does the will of God is My brother and sister and mother.””  This means that many do not do the will of God.
John 7:17 – “If anyone’s will is to do God’s will, he will know whether the teaching is from God or whether I am speaking on my own authority.”  This specifically allows for our wills to be different from God’s will.
Eph 5:17 – “Therefore do not be foolish, but understand what the Lord’s will is.”  That is, many do not do the will of God.
1 Thess 4:3 – “For it is God’s will that you should be holy: You must abstain from sexual immorality”.  However, we know that many do not.
1 Peter 2:15 – “ For it is God’s will that you should be holy: You must abstain from sexual immorality;”  Again, this is not always the case.
1 Peter 4:2 – “Consequently, he does not live out his remaining time on earth for human passions, but for the will of God.”  That is, we have a choice as to whether we follow human will/passions or God’s will.
1 John 2:17 – “The world is passing away, along with its desires; but whoever does the will of God remains forever.”  That is, we choose whether to do God’s will or not.

The message here is profound – doing God’s will is not forced upon people.  Service to God should be because of love and thus, entirely voluntary.  God is still sovereign but man is responsible.
This appears to be the whole subject of scripture from Adam and Eve’s fall (who sinned against God’s will), to Joseph’s betrayal when he famously said:

Gen 50:20 - As for you, what you intended against me for evil, God
intended for good, in order to accomplish a day like this—to preserve
the lives of many people.

CONCLUSION
It is clear that God wants "all to saved and come to the knowledge of the truth".  God's work and will is to save all people.  However, some do not do the will of God.

Indeed, some choose not to receive the one the Father sent. +1

@Dottard Thanks. You quote 1 Tim 2:4. There is a question on this site - "In Timothy 2:4 does "all" refer to all men or all "sorts" of men?" The answers to this question suggest the possible ambiguity of this verse.

@C.Stroud - the Greek is quite clear - it says "all people".  "kinds" is absent from the text and cannot be inserted arbitrarily.

@Dottard In 1 Tim 2:1 Paul says, "all people" and immediately expands on this to give examples of "all people" i.e., "kings and all who are in high positions" i.e., types or sorts of people. Why should , or should not, this meaning of "all people" go from v1-2 to  "all people" in v4?

@C.Stroud - All means all.  I read "everyone— for kings and all those in authority" to be an inclusive statement - all including rulers.

Answer
Two factors each need to be considered to assess the Will of God; the long term goal and the short term goals of God on one hand and the Will of God (faith) and the free will (works) He gave to human beings on the other hand.
Explanation
The Scripture talks about a long term Goal or Will of God which He has set for all humanity:
Long Term Goal
Even before creating Adam and Eve, God had set His long term goal for the entire humanity in place.

“In all his wisdom and insight God did what he had purposed, and made
known to us the secret plan (Will=Thelema) he had already decided to
complete by means of Christ. This plan, which God will complete when
the time is right, is to bring all creation together, everything in
heaven and on earth, with Christ as head. All things are done
according to God's plan and decision” (Eph 1:8-11).

In other words:

“God our Savior, who wills all men to be saved, and to come to the
full knowledge of the truth” (1 Tim 2:3-4).

Short Term Goals
However, during the course of human history, God has set various short term goals which do not disturb His ultimate long term goal in any way.
One example:

“And I will harden Pharaoh's heart, and he will pursue you. And I will
be honored through Pharaoh, and through all his armies. And the
Egyptians shall know that I am Jehovah. And they did so” (Exo
14:4).

Does the above mean that Pharaoh is lost forever?
Not at all.
“Being ignorant”, Pharaoh “did it in unbelief” (because God had hardened his heart in His short term goal) so that he will “receive mercy” (in the long term goal) – 1 Tim 1:13.

“For God has shut up all in unbelief (short term goal), so that He
might show mercy to all (long term goal)” - Rom 11:32.


“Indeed as regards the gospel, they (Jews) are enemies for your sakes
(short term goal). But as regards the election, they are beloved for
the fathers' sakes (long term goal) – Rom 11:28.


“And so all Israel shall be saved” (long term goal) – verse 26.

Will of God
The ultimate Will of God is stated in the Scripture:

“In just the same way your Father in heaven does not want any of these
little ones to be lost” (Mat 18:14).

However, God has given a true free will to humanity so that the latter would (should) follow God through self-volition and love.

“Behold, I have set before you today life and good and death and evil,
… I call Heaven and earth to witness against you today that I have set
before you life and death, the blessing and the curse. Therefore,
choose life, that you may live, you and your seed” (Deut 30:15, 19).

We may see clearly that God gives “choices” of life and death. He doesn’t “force” anyone to love Him but “advises” to choose life.
The ultimate decision is on each individual and this is the free will which is real.
So chances are there that some may not follow good advice. Hence we read in Mat 7:19:

“Every tree that doesn't produce good fruit will be cut down and
thrown into a fire”.

Also,

“For how can those who abandon their faith be brought back to repent
again? They were once in God's light; they tasted heaven's gift and
received their share of the Holy Spirit (they were true Christians); they knew from experience that God's word is good, and
they had felt the powers of the coming age. And then they abandoned
their faith! It is impossible to bring them back to repent again,
because they are again crucifying the Son of God and exposing him to
public shame” (Heb 6:4-6).

The above case is the result of the will of each man and not the Will of God.
The free will God gave us is real and true.
Faith and Works
This is a very controversial issue debated through centuries. However, the answer is simple. Faith is a gift from God:

“For by grace you are saved, through faith, and this not of
yourselves; it is the gift of God” (Eph 2:8).

Faith is a free gift from God given through the Holy Spirit. It is through faith that we believe. This is only a beginning. But faith alone will not do. We need to convert this faith into fruits of good works.
Faith is like the life sap in a tree through which the tree brings forth its fruits. So, Jesus Himself said:

“every tree is known by its own fruit” (Luke 6:44);

not by its leaves, or stem or roots.
Finally in the last judgment, God judges people based on their “works” done through their faith and not by their faith alone:

“And I saw the dead, the small and the great, standing before God. And
books were opened. And another Book was opened, which is the Book of
Life. And the dead were judged out of the things written in the books,
according to their WORKS” (Rev 20:12).


“And the sea gave up the dead in it. And death and hell gave up the
dead in them. And they were each judged according to their WORKS”
(Rev 20:13).

Paul himself says:

“God “will give to each according to his WORKS” (Rom 2:6).


“But are you willing to know, O vain man, that faith apart from works
is dead?... For as the body is dead apart from the spirit, so also
faith is dead apart from works” (James 2:20, 26).

So, the whole point is: faith is God’s free gift. But man has to respond actively and positively through good works.

“And so, my dear friends, just as you have always obeyed, not only
when I was with you but even more now that I am absent, continue to
WORK OUT your salvation with fear and trembling” (Php 2:12).

Conclusion
The ultimate long term Will of God is to save the entire humanity. God gives faith as a gift to the called out ones. But since man is given true free will, God will not force anyone to respond. It is entirely up to each individual to respond actively and positively through good works.
However, God has short term goals which in no way affect the ultimate Will of God.

God's will for a man is to obey him and do the works appointed to that man.  Most important among those works is to believe in His son, Jesus. But God has given man the authority to do this, so this will can be violated by a man.
God's will for himself is always obeyed (by himself), and thus cannot be violated.
For the first case, we see that most men have violated God's will in 1Ti 2:4 "(God) will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth.
In the second case, in Rom 15:32 we see Paul recognizing that God's sovereign will necessarily trumps his own choices: "so that I may come to you with joy, by God's will, and in your company be refreshed."
Clearly Mark 3:35 is a situation where a man has been given the authority, and chooses to obey and do God's will, as particularly and most importantly seen in: Jhn 6:29 Jesus answered and said unto them, This is the work of God, that ye believe on him whom he hath sent.

Thanks. Please see my comment to Dottard. 1 Tim 2:4 all- all men or all types even kings etc: as in verses 1-2.

I think the meaning of "all people" is the same.  The gift in 1 Tim 2:6 is given to all, but not received by all.
